# Adding Firebase Script Tags In The HTML File

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a front end website to talk to a Firestore Database and have been following the official documentation for the new version 9 modules but I have given up with this route as I just keep getting errors so I have started looking at another tutorial which I have got working but I have a question regarding the html head script tags.

In the html  I have the following.

```
  <!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- Add additional services you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.3/firebase-firestore.js"></script>>
```

My question is:
Am I ok to use version 5.03 or is it likely this will get removed from the gstatic.com in due course now they are moving over to version 9 modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Firebase doesn't remove SDKs from its CDNs. You can still find our `0.9` and event `0.0` SDK versions there, and in fact (I happened to recently check some usage statistic) they are still being used (luckily very sparingly ).

That said, I recommend upgrading to a more recent version to ensure you get the latest improvements and fixes. I get that the new modular syntax in v9 may be a big step, so a first step towards that could be to [use the `compat` versions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat), which are drop-in compatible with v8 (and often earlier versions).

Comment: thank you for the clarification on this.